# CSS stretch all divs in one line

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS, I try to stretch the divs to make their content fit. You can see it at the right list, the childs size extends the parent size (thats why I added the `border`). So I tried adding `align-items: stretch` to the `container` `div`, but that does not work.
I could add this rule to each `div`, but this will result for example in the left side getting bigger, while the right one stays the same. I want to avoid this, instead I want the complete line (both `div`s) to be stretched if one gets stretched.
I hope you understand what I want to achieve.
I know that the CSS is quite large, but I posted everything to make sure there is no fault by me I missed.

For clarification:
I want to maximize the size of the `div` when the content does not fit in **when the window size is getting smaller** (like the first left div): The headline is placed inside the text because there is no space left)

**Update**
Just noticed that stretch is a bit confusing due to this CSS property, I thin grow is a better term.
The divs should grow when the content does not fit into them.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;     
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.container > div > a > .dot{
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s linear;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 101;
    height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container > div > a  > .dot > .arrow-down {
  transition: border .2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top:11%;
  left: 24%;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container > div > a .dot:hover{
  background: black;
}
.container > div > a .dot:hover > .arrow-down{
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.container > div > a > .dot > .arrow-down{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.video-iframe.fullsize{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.list{
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .half-width-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > h1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 15%;
}

.half-width-text > .middle-text{
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.full-width > .content > .third-parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third{
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;

  width: 100%;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2  li{
   position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-div2 li::before{
  content: '\2022';
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.items-list2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
<iframe class="video-iframe fullsize" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/osg9PmkfTB0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <a href="#section2">
      <span class="dot">
        <i class="arrow-down"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
              <h1>Headline</h1>
      <div class="half-width-text">
        <div class="text-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="1">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="2">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Hello">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Bye">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=BLA">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
 <div class="middle-text">
 <h2>Headline</h2>
 <p>
 This is some text paragraph
 </p>
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
          <li>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam </li>
          <li>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</li>
          <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What divs are you talking about?

Comment: All that contain content, which will be every div with the class .half-width-content and in the last container every div with the class .third

Comment: If you add some border or background color to the .third divs, you'll see they are the same height by the way.

Comment: I know, but If I make the window smaller, the content overlaps (like in the first left div with the long text). And thats what I want to avoid by stretching out the size of the div

Comment: Mostly likely caused by position: absolute elements, avoid it, or reset it in media queries.

Comment: I need this absolute for some animation stuff (which is not included here for simplification)

Comment: Well, maybe you won't need the animations on mobile, it's too much code to tweak here.

Comment: They are disabled at mobile, it is just an 'not-nice' effect on desktop, if the height gets to less:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what do you want. You are using `left` and `top` with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` that's where you are making mistakes.

I have commented unwanted CSS and added the alternate.. Please check below.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;     
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.container > div > a > .dot{
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s linear;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 101;
    height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container > div > a  > .dot > .arrow-down {
  transition: border .2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top:11%;
  left: 24%;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container > div > a .dot:hover{
  background: black;
}
.container > div > a .dot:hover > .arrow-down{
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.container > div > a > .dot > .arrow-down{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;   
  position:relative;           
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow: auto
}

.video-iframe.fullsize{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.list{
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*left: 50%;
  top:50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .half-width-text {
  /*position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.half-width#section2 > .half-width-content, .half-width#section3 > .half-width-content {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

 .half-width > .half-width-content > h1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  /*top: 15%;*/
}

.half-width-text > .middle-text{
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.list-div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-div ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;

}

.list-div li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.full-width > .content > .third-parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third{
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;

  width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text{
  /*position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2  li{
   position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-div2 li::before{
  content: '\2022';
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.items-list2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
<iframe class="video-iframe fullsize" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/osg9PmkfTB0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <a href="#section2">
      <span class="dot">
        <i class="arrow-down"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
              <h1>Headline</h1>
      <div class="half-width-text">
        <div class="text-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="1">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="2">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Hello">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Bye">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=BLA">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width" id="section3">
    <div class="half-width-content">
 <div class="middle-text">
 <h2>Headline</h2>
 <p>
 This is some text paragraph
 </p>
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list" id="list">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
          <li>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam </li>
          <li>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua</li>
          <li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width" id="section4">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also test it here. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/gda5f643/36/

Comment: oh boy, thats brilliant. will this work for the 'bottom' three divs the same way? +1:)

Comment: Thanks a lot, there is only one problem:) The text and the list arent centered vertically anymore:)

Comment: Just change `text-align: left;` to `text-align: center;`  in `.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text > .list-div2  li` and `.list-div li` style. And you are done :)

Comment: I tried that already, but this is only the align from 'left to right', but I need 'top to down', that was what the translate was for:D

Comment: thanks for your effort, but now the growth of the divs does not work anymore:) got my reason why I asked on SO:D

Comment: Oh my God, really appreciate that :) just one more thing:D the list at the bottom is not centered (it should look like it does in my question)

Comment: Sorry for late, but here you go.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/gda5f643/36/ don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: just one last thing:D it seems that the images at the last div (#section3) are not centered but topped (or the list is to far at the bottom). I cant find the error (images there have also the align:center). Could you help me one more time?